# jQuery.validate, form with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

***I have the following form:***

[image]

***Seems easy to validate but now I have some conditionals for it:***

- At least one row of `name`, `email` inputs must be completed (`form` can't be empty when pressing *Finish* button).
- If user completes **1**, **2** or all rows of `name`, `email` inputs, the `form` must validate the rows that the user has completed when pressing *Finish* button.

*(Just to know, the validation will take place just when Finish button gets pressed. That's why I removed the live validation, take a look at the first lines of my code in the jsFiddle template link at the end of my post).*

---

Well, to achieve this my first idea was to detect which `name` inputs has text.

Then capture the `name` inputs with text and create a `jQuery.validate` instance to validate those names with their `email` inputs too.

The problem is that I don't know how to declare the `jQuery.validate` of my `form` that just validates the rows that the user has completed. It seems hard to do considering that the user can complete the rows in any order and clear them at any moment. This means that the validation must change and previous error messages must dissapear.

This is what I got by now: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/fFD8m/1/)** but seems messy and It will be better to know if there is a method of `jQuery.validate` to achieve this kind of `form` validation.

*(I am not sure if I am clear of what I am trying to do but, if something is not clear, just comment and ask me).*

---

***I made this template if someone wants to help:***

**[jsFiddle template](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/FNcuJ/)**

---

***Just to know, the `html` can be modified, also if you guys know another way or plugin for this just suggest it.***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started by modifying the HTML part. I added classes, but more importantly, I added data-set on the inputs.

```
<form id="inviteForm" action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr class="sets set-1">
            <td>Name: <input data-set="1" class="input-name" name="name_1" type="text" value=""/></td>
            <td>E-mail: <input data-set="1" class="input-email" name="email_1" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sets set-2">
            <td>Name: <input data-set="2" class="input-name" name="name_2" type="text" value=""/></td>
            <td>E-mail: <input data-set="2" class="input-email" name="email_2" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sets set-3">
            <td>Name: <input data-set="3" class="input-name" name="name_3" type="text" value=""/></td>
            <td>E-mail: <input data-set="3" class="input-email" name="email_3" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sets set-4">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Finish"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>​
```

I also added classes on the TR. This is a useful technique. you can call all the TR with $(".sets") or a specific one with $(".set-1"). You will see why this is useful below.

Then, I declared a default variables for rules.

```
var defaultrules = {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 50,
            messages: {
                required: "*",
                minlength: jQuery.format("Min. {0} characters"),
                maxlength: jQuery.format("Max. {0} characters")
            }
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 150,
            messages: {
                required: "*",
                email: "Invalid format",
                minlength: jQuery.format("Min. {0} characters"),
                maxlength: jQuery.format("Max. {0} characters")
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, I listened on the inputs for change. When the input changed, I simply added the rules to the validation

```
$("#inviteForm input").on("change", function() {
        var ele = $(this);

        // Get the set!
        cur_set = ele.data("set");

        // Is it filled? 
        if (ele.val().length > 0) {
            // Add the rules to the current set, to the corresponding inputs
            $(".set-"+cur_set).find(".input-name").rules('add', defaultrules.name)
            $(".set-"+cur_set).find(".input-email").rules('add', defaultrules.email)
        }
    })
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maktouch/DC8eJ/1/

Comment: I really appreciate your effort on this and also your time. There are few things I have to modify but you got the idea. Thank you very much! :-)